# Is there a way to use the jQuery selector to get the same string as returned by document.documentElement.outerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I was wondering if there is an alternative to using the Javascript: `document.documentElement.outerHTML` 
that possibly utilizes the jQuery selector and other jQuery methods if they exist. Or, if there is any other more efficient ways of getting a string containing the entire source code of a webpage using Javascript and or Jquery.

Comment: What's wrong with the method you're using? Just looking for Firefox support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var source = "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
```

That was the quick and easy way but, like someone said, it will only return the HTML within the `<html></html>` tags. It would not include stuff found outside of the `<html></html>` tags, like the doctype.

To get everything, you can use `jQuery.ajax()` to request the page and get the whole shebang.

```
var source = 'Unable to retrieve source code';
$.ajax(
    "your/webpage/here.html",
    {
        async    : false,
        success  : function(data) {source = data;}
    }
);
alert(source);    // or whatever
```

The request was made synchronously, in this example, so that we could do whatever with the source after the request returns. You could make the call asynchronously and put all of your code in the success function.

Here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4rkdF/

Answer (score 0):

Using just jQuery I'd probably do something like this:

```
$('#theDesiredElement').wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/d4WCg/

Comment: I think I understand how that code might be applicable to the situation, but how exactly would I alter that code to get the entire source code of the page?

Comment: @patrick dw I guess there is nothing that is particularly wrong with the method I am using as far as I know, but I was just wondering if there was an alternative that exists using jQuery which would allow me to print out all the source code of the page.

Comment: @Kevin Gurney: Not sure of a way to go above the html element, the highest I'd think you can go with just jQuery is `$('html').html()`, which will return everything within the html tags. That may or may not be your entire page.

Comment: @Robert: I sort of thought that might be the case. Ok, well thank you for the help Robert! I guess I will just have to stick with document.documentElement.outerHTML for now.

Comment: @Kevin Gurney: You may want to look into compatibility for that. I believe Firefox may not support that.

Answer (score 0):

example markup:

```
<div id="help"> help </div>
```

jQuery

```
var outerHTML = $('<div>').html($('#help')).html();
```

create `<div>` on the fly using `$('<div>')`. Then get `<div id="help">` by `$('#help')`. Afterward put `$('#help')` inside the created div. And get the html of the created div.